# Chrome Extension / cookie / await a callback function

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension, async-await

Hi I'm sorry for asking this, I did lot of research but I can't solve this probleme, I can't get the value of my cookie I think it's because my function have a callback, (I get the value after my code) but I don't know fix it :/

```
const cookieUrl = 'http://urlCookie'
const cookieName = 'CookieName'

cookieValue = checkCookie(cookieUrl,cookieName)
console.log('cookieValue: ', cookieValue)

function checkCookie(url, name){
    chrome.cookies.get({
        url: url,
        name: name
    },
    function (cookie) {
        if (cookie) {
        console.log(cookie.value)
        return cookie.value
        }
        else {
        console.log('Can\'t get cookie! Check the name!')
        return 0
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of Chrome API didn't return a promise when we call them, we have to provide it a callback to handle the response. So in this case we could add a promise and resolve it inside the callback so that we can have a *signal* when chrome call the callback.

```
const cookieUrl = 'http://urlCookie'
const cookieName = 'CookieName'

cookieValue = checkCookie(cookieUrl,cookieName)
    .then((cookie) => console.log(cookie))
    .catch(function(error) {console.log(error)});

function checkCookie(url, name){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        chrome.cookies.get({
            url: url,
            name: name
        },
        function (cookie) {
            if (cookie) {
                console.log(cookie.value)
                resolve(cookie.value)
            }
            else {
                console.log('Can\'t get cookie! Check the name!')
                reject(0);
            }
        })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Guys,
My last code :

```
const myFunction = async () => {
    try {
        let cookieValue = await checkCookie(cookieUrl,cookieName)
        console.log('cookie is present',cookieValue )

    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
} 
function checkCookie(url, name){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        chrome.cookies.get({
            url: url,
            name: name
        },
        function (cookie) {
            if (cookie) {
                console.log('cookieValue',cookie.value)
                resolve(cookie.value)
            }
            else {
                reject('Can\'t get cookie! Check the name!')
            }
        })
    });
}

myFunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// assuming chrome.cookies.get
function checkCookie(url, name) {
  return chrome.cookies.get({url, name}, cookie => cookie);
}
var cookie = checkCookie(url, name)
```

I'm not very familiar with the chrome.cookies.get, and so have no idea how to test this, but any rational function employing callbacks would return the value of the callback.

Alternatively, you could wrap it in a promise

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
async function get_cookies(cookie_name, domen) {
  let obj = await chrome.cookies.get({
    name: cookie_name,
    url: domen
  });
  let value = obj.value;
  return value;
}

// your main function must be asynchronous then you can run "await" inside this function and get cookie_val in the general code flow
async function youBaseFunc() {
  var cookie_val = await get_cookies('cookie_name', 'cookie_domen');
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is an English-only site. Please translate your answer and code comments into English or they will be removed from the site. If you're interested in helping users in other languages there are international sites such as [ru.so] availalble.